# How to create an API route in new SvelteKit update?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

[This app](https://github.com/JannikWempe/svelte-auth) was a great starter for SvelteKit users trying to implement authentication, but after [these breaking changes](https://www.netlify.com/blog/migrating-breaking-changes-in-sveltekit/) in v406 the API methods no longer work. This is what the code to hit the route is:

```js
const response = await fetch("/api/sign-in", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

And this is an example of the tree structure for the routes:

[image: Old SvelteKit route tree path]

How do I get transform this to make the old routes accessible with the new routing convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new routing convention, the contents of `api/sign-in.ts` need to be moved to `api/sign-in/+server.ts`. Once in the new file, they need to be wrapped in the method(s) you need for the route. An simple example of the syntax for a `POST` request route is:

```js
export async function POST({ request }: { request: Request }) {
  const { email, password } = await request.json();

  // ...
  // Insert your real logic here
  // ...

  // An example of a simple response
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({
    message: "Hello world!"
  }, {
    status: 200
  });
}
```

So you would just need to drop your authentication logic into the new file with the correct wrapper, whether that is `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc. Note that the endpoints are required to be all caps now, more information is available [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5359).

Comment: Must the `+page.svelte` file be present?

 It's returning 404 when a request is made to `/api/update/+server.ts`. But after adding `+page.svelte`, it worked.

I

Comment: @ikwuje when you're trying to make an API request, the `+page.svelte` is not required; if you're wanting to be able to actually visit the page in the browser instead of sending a `GET`/`POST` request, *then* a `+page.svelte` file is required.